# How do I check if a variable implements an interface in clojure?

Tags: clojure

So I have defined say a keyword:

```
(def a :hello)
```

how do I check that it implements the IFn interface?

Comment: Why do you want to? It could indicate a broken design.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the general case, you can use the [`instance?`](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-(instance?%20Class%20expr)) predicate:

```
(instance? <class-or-interface> <object>)
```

Quoting the documentation:

> `(instance? c x)` evaluates x and tests if it is an instance of the class
>   c. Returns true or false.

For example:

```
(instance? java.lang.String "test")
> true

(instance? java.io.Serializable "test")
> true
```

For the code in the question, do something like this:

```
(instance? package.of.IFn a)
```

Or, as has been pointed out in the comments, for the very specific case of asking if `a` is an instance of `IFn` this will work:

```
(ifn? a)
```

Comment: Even better, use `(ifn? a)`.

Comment: @DaveRay How so? I didn't know that an interface automatically comes with a testing predicate, where is this explained in the documentation? does it work for Java interfaces, like `Serializable`?

Comment: No, there isn't a generic predicate for every type, but the question asked how to test for `IFn`, in which case, `ifn?` would I guess be more idiomatic than using `instance?`. Similarly, I'd use `string?` instead of your first example.