# Clojure, reflection: Find classes that implement an interface

Tags: java, reflection, interface, clojure, classpath

This seems to be a more difficult in Clojure than in Java and Scala. What I want to do is:

1. Define an interface in Java
2. Implement it in a class in Clojure (Bonus: with a macro)
3. Find it using the classloader and reflection

This is what I have so far:

## The Java interface

```
package hello.interfaces;
public interface Test {
    String doSomething(String input);
}
```

## The Clojure definition

```
(ns hello.impl.test
  (:gen-class
    :implements [hello.interfaces.Test]))

(defn doSomething [v] (str "hello " v))
```

## Searching for the classes:

```
(ns hello.core
  (:import
    (org.reflections Reflections)
    (org.reflections.util ConfigurationBuilder))
  (:gen-class))

(defn -instances []
  (let [paths (into-array Object ["hello"])]
      (.getSubTypesOf (Reflections. paths) hello.interfaces.Test)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (-instances)))
```

I am using [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). This works if I search for classes that are in the classpath (e.g. in the `org.reflections` jar) but it does not work for my previously defined class, therefore I think that the problem is not in the last snippet of code but in the previous one, or maybe in the usage, e.g. it requires pre-compiling it.

How can I define classes in Clojure that I can find later with reflection?

Comment: I must say that I am very new to Clojure, this is in fact the first piece of code that I am trying to write, so sorry for the noob question. My main interest in Clojure is in metaprogramming, so I hope that the implementation of interfaces using macros is compatible with this usage. In Scala (previous version) I am using implicit conversions instead of macros, but macros seem better to avoid boilerplate.

Comment: never used Java interfaces in such a way, just making sure that you are aware of `instance?` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12170685/1327651

Comment: @nha I am not aware of most of Clojure things yet. In this case, `instance?` is not a suitable option, as it works with objects to check if they are instances of a class. I am searching for classes, and once found the first thing to do is call their constructors to build their corresponding objects. What I am trying to do may not be conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with org.reflections, but if you just want a list of loaded classes, you can get it with the below code:

```
(let [classloader (.getClassLoader clojure.main)
      classes-field (.getDeclaredField java.lang.ClassLoader "classes")]
  (.setAccessible classes-field true)
  (let [class-list (.get classes-field classloader)
        class-vec (reduce conj [] class-list)] ; copy everything into a new vector rather than working directly with the classloader's private field
    class-vec))
```

It sounds like you're familiar with Java, so I guess you can see the above is basically just translated Java. It will only give you the classes which have been loaded with the same class loader as that for the class `clojure.main`, but if you haven't done any customisation with your class loaders, that should be enough.

Once you have that list, you can search/filter it however you want. Of course, the class you're looking for does have to have been loaded first. If that's not the case, you'll have to search the classpath instead.

=== UPDATE to respond to your comment ===

OK I see, you're asking how to create a class. The first thing to say is that you don't generally need to create named classes when you're writing Clojure, unless you specifically want to use some existing Java code which requires you to do so. If you're writing pure Clojure, you just write your functions and work with them directly.

However, you can of course do so. The first part of the doc for `gen-class` states:

> ### => (doc gen-class)
>
> clojure.core/gen-class
>
> ([& options])
>
> Macro
>
> When compiling, generates compiled bytecode for a class with the
>     given package-qualified :name (which, as all names in these
>     parameters, can be a string or symbol), and writes the .class file
>     to the *compile-path* directory.  When not compiling, does
>     nothing.

So, you need to compile your namespace. I don't normally do this so I don't know if there's a way to do it without creating .class files, and just creating the classes directly in memory, but the below does what you want, if I've understood you correctly:

```
(ns wip.test)

; looks for wip/himplement.clj on the classpath, and compiles it into .class files
; requires that ../bin is in the classpath
(binding [*compile-path* "../bin"]
     (compile 'wip.himplement))

; loads the wip.himplement class from the .class files
(Class/forName "wip.himplement")


; create a list of all loaded classes (could presumably also be done with org.reflections)
(def classes-list (let [classloader (.getClassLoader clojure.main)
                        classes-field (.getDeclaredField java.lang.ClassLoader "classes")]
                    (.setAccessible classes-field true)
                    (java.util.ArrayList. (.get classes-field classloader))))

; Outputs all loaded classes which implement HInterface. Output is:
; (wip.hello.HInterface wip.himplement)
(println (filter #(isa? % wip.hello.HInterface) classes-list))
```

Comment: Thank you.`org.reflections` gives me the classes that implement an interface, but I could not create a class implementing an interface in Clojure. Here is the corresponding code: https://github.com/trylks/wip you can just do `lein run`

Comment: this works. Thank you. The problem is reflection requires ahead of time compilation, there are several ways to achieve it. One is what you mention, other is in `project.clj` for Leiningen. I am currently using `lein compile :all`. Maybe worth mentioning that this is not a problem for dependencies because they are compiled and packed into `.jar` files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve, but there are a few things that I should probably point you in the direction of. Firstly there's a namespace called `clojure.reflect` that contains useful functions for getting info about classes. It makes it easier to reflect the Java hierarchy at the REPL. Secondly there's things like [clojure.tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) that will help you traverse the code in your repo and find all the namespaces that implement interfaces. However, you tend to use `deftype` to implement classes rather than using the AOT compiler features like the `:gen-class` option in the `ns` macro, unless you're implementing something specific like a servelet or something.